# In the proof of $R\otimes_R N\cong N$ in Dummit and Foote

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

The following is an excerpt from Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*:

> [image]

Theorem 8 is as follows:
[image]

---

One can tell immediately from Theorem 8 that $\Phi\circ\iota=id_N$, which implies that $\iota$ is [injective](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injection_iff_Left_Inverse). But how does Theorem 8 imply that $\iota$ is actually an *isomorphism*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to deduce it from Theorem 8.  Apply Theorem 8 with $S=R$, $L=R\otimes_R N$, and $\varphi=\iota$.  You get that there is a unique $\Psi:R\otimes_R N\to R\otimes_R N$ such that $\iota=\Psi\circ\iota$.  Of course, one such $\Psi$ is the identity map.  But since $\Phi\circ \iota=id_N$, another such $\Psi$ is $\iota\circ\Phi$: $$(\iota\circ\Phi)\circ\iota=\iota\circ(\Phi\circ\iota)=\iota\circ id_N=\iota.$$  By uniqueness of $\Psi$, $\iota\circ\Phi=id_{R\otimes_R N}$.  Together with $\Phi\circ \iota=id_N$, this proves $\iota$ is an isomorphism with inverse $\Phi$.